# Python versions and pyenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, homebrew, pyenv

I installed **python3** using homebrew, but I stumbled upon many posts mentioning that it is better to use **pyenv** to manage different python versions. However, I have not found a post that answers my question:

Should I uninstall python3, install pyenv, and then reinstall python3 using pyenv? Or should I just install pyenv now, would this work?

Below is output from terminal:

System python

```
python --version
Python 2.7.18

which python
/usr/bin/python
```

Python3

```
python3 --version
Python 3.9.10

which python3
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3
```

Comment: Are you actually going to be managing _multiple_ Python versions? It's quite common to have both Python 2.7 (installed by default on many operating systems) and Python 3 (for actual programming). They can coexist just fine, so there's no need for any extra management.

Comment: I guess it can work as it is for now, but when python4 gets released (it is expected soon I think) won't I need something to manage the two versions?

Comment: I haven't heard of Python 4 being released anytime soon. In fact, Guido van Rossum [said](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/programming-languages-why-python-4-0-will-probably-never-arrive-according-to-its-creator/) not that long ago that Python 4 may never be a thing.

Comment: Alright, that's good to know then. I might not be needing the version control after all.

Comment: you don't need tools to manage different versions - you can have even installed `3.9` with `3.8`, `3.7`, etc. and use commands `python3.9`, `python3.8`, `python3.7` and also `pip3.9`, `pip3.8`, `pip3.6`

Comment: If you want to use `pyenv` then you can have in on top of the ordinary installs. So don't uninstall those that you have.

Answer (score 0):

From https://justinmayer.com/posts/homebrew-python-is-not-for-you/

> Homebrew’s Python is not for you. It exists to serve Homebrew, or more accurately, Homebrew’s other formulae. The primary purpose of Homebrew’s Python formula is to enable other Python-dependent Homebrew packages to work. If installing Homebrew’s Python allows you to run the occasional Python script or access the REPL, that’s a nice side benefit, but anything beyond that — including developing software with Python — is squarely out-of-scope.

You can run `brew uses --installed python` to check if any installed packages depend on Homebrew Python. If no packages are listed, then you can safely uninstall via `brew uninstall python` and use pyenv instead.